# Netlify deployment failed: "Base directory does not exist"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy my react app on Netlify and I get this error on Netlify:

```
7:59:54 PM: build-image version: e70ad4c6ce38c2b84143366f988574c7090c7a66 (focal)
7:59:54 PM: buildbot version: 4c288ae79a050d892a0d956d88b51697b8d4b77a
7:59:54 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
7:59:54 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
7:59:54 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
7:59:54 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
7:59:54 PM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/DeBoer753/cbm-APP
7:59:54 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
7:59:56 PM: Failing build: Failed to parse configuration
7:59:56 PM: Failed during stage "Reading and parsing configuration files": 
When resolving config file /opt/build/repo/netlify.toml:
Base directory does not exist: /opt/build/repo/cbm-app
```

My base directory in my project is cbm-app (shown as all caps in vs code, but created as lower case as a folder in my GUI)

I have a netlify.toml file that holds:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/"
  status = 200

  [build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "build" # or the directory where your build artifacts are located
```

My package.json holds:

```
{
  "name": "m-photo-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I wish to continue to deploy more sites that will essentially be identical to the project I have now with all same dependencies. I only make front end sites using React and CSS along with some third-party icon instalments.

My GitHub repo is: https://github.com/DeBoer753/cbm-APP

Comment: I wonder if it is a case issue. Your repo is called `cbm-APP` and Netlify is looking for `cbm-app`. Could you rename your repo?

Comment: I was able to get it to work after deleting my build file and all the contents within it. I  also didn't touch anythign when asked to fill out pre deployment questions like "base directory" during Netlfiy pre-deploy. After deploying I came across errors within my netlify and it said I needed to get rid of eslint errors in mhy original code. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work after deleting my build file and all the contents within it. I also didn't touch anything when asked to fill out pre deployment questions like "base directory" during Netlfiy deployment. After deploying I came across errors within my netlify under the "Buidling" drop down and it said I needed to get rid of eslint errors in my original code. Now it works.